# How to retrieve user details in follow button callback function in twitter api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have tried to retrieve logged in user name and location details in follow button callback function.

```
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
   twttr.events.bind('follow', function (event) {
      $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?user_id=" + event.data.user_id,
            success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
            }
       });                  
    });
 });
```

But I couldn't able to retrieve user details. Is it possible to retrieve user details?

Comment: why you delete your `ABCD` question?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, Some people having habit of downvoting question instead giving help to below users. That is why frustrated and deleted my question.

Comment: Dont give up so fast, I was about to try to give you an answer. Looks like you have been here long enough to realize sometime other have hard time understanding your question. Just spend a litle more time writing the question.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, Yes I understand. Is my question difficult to understand to you? If you have solution for that ABCD question, kindly post the solution here.

Comment: I cant, my answer was delete when I was writting because your question disapear

Comment: Wasnt 100% clear but I was guessing where could be the error. My suggestion create a sample with real data in http://sqlfiddle.com that help a lot to replicate your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like show already include user detail https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show

Example Result:

```
{
  "contributors_enabled": false,
  "created_at": "Sat Dec 14 04:35:55 +0000 2013",
  "default_profile": false,
  "default_profile_image": false,
  "description": "Developer and Platform Relations @Twitter. We are developer advocates. We can't answer all your questions, but we listen to all of them!",
  "entities": {
    "description": {
      "urls": []
    },
    "url": {
      "urls": [
        {
          "display_url": "dev.twitter.com",
          "expanded_url": "https://dev.twitter.com/",
          "indices": [
            0,
            23
          ],
          "url": "https://t.co/66w26cua1O"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "favourites_count": 757,
  "follow_request_sent": false,
  "followers_count": 143916,
  "following": false,
  "friends_count": 1484,
  "geo_enabled": true,
  "id": 2244994945,
  "id_str": "2244994945",
  "is_translation_enabled": false,
  "is_translator": false,
  "lang": "en",
  "listed_count": 516,
  "location": "Internet",
  "name": "TwitterDev",
  "notifications": false,
  "profile_background_color": "FFFFFF",
  "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
```